# Is it safe to maintain an LMDB handle to the same file from every thread?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, lmdb

I'm building a multi-threaded server that uses LMDB as a database. It uses multiple threads to performantly handle high request volumes.

Is it safe to maintain an LMDB instance for the `.mdb` file on every thread and access the database concurrently, or is it better to share a single instance between threads with a mutex?

Also, does LMDB handle write locking itself or do I need to manually maintain a mutex to lock write operations if I do opt to open the database once on each thread?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Single lmdb instance to be used throughout your application across all threads

Lmdb will handle all the locking - you don't need to do the mutex logic